# Invalid SQL statement in UpdateCursor using ArcPy

Tags: python, sql

I am trying to determine qualitative distances (Very Close, Close, and Far) of different sized cities (Small, Medium, Large) using an Update Cursor and keep getting this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 34, in <module>
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT NEAR_DIST, MedCities, OBJECTID_1 FROM popPlaces WHERE EST_POP>500ANDEST_POP<=10000]
```

The code I am using is as follows:

```
#Task 7: Provide a qualitative classification of distance to hospitals for different size cities
#Create qualitative fields
arcpy.management.AddFields('popPlaces', [['SmallCities','TEXT'],['MedCities','TEXT'],['LargeCities','TEXT']])
#Assign qualitiative city size variabes to new fields
small=popCol+"<="+"500"
medium=popCol+">"+"500"+ "AND" +popCol+"<="+"10000"
large=popCol+">10000"
print('small', 'medium', 'large')

#Create an Update Cursor separately for the different size cities that assigns a qualitative class to each record based on distance to hospital.
#For SmallCities
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(popPlaces,(Dist,"SmallCities"),small) as cursor:
 for i in cursor:
  if i[0] <= 1000:
   i[1] = "Very Close"
  elif i[0] > 1000 and i[0] < 10000:
   i[1] = 'Close'
  else:
   i[1] = 'Far'
  cursor.updateRow(i)

#For LargeCities
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(popPlaces,(Dist,"LargeCities"),large) as cursor:
 for i in cursor:
  if i[0] <= 1000:
   i[1] = "Very Close"
  elif i[0] > 1000 and i[0] < 10000:
   i[1] = 'Close'
  else:
   i[1] = 'Far'
  cursor.updateRow(i)

#For MedCities
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(popPlaces,(Dist,"MedCities"),medium) as cursor:
 for i in cursor:
  if i[0] <= 1000:
   i[1] = "Very Close"
  elif i[0] > 1000 and i[0] < 10000:
   i[1] = 'Close'
  else:
   i[1] = 'Far'
  cursor.updateRow(i)
```

The Cursor works for Small and Large Cities but not Medium cities and I'm unsure where I've gone wrong. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing spaces around `AND` in

```
EST_POP>500ANDEST_POP<=10000
```

Change

```
medium=popCol+">"+"500"+ "AND" +popCol+"<="+"10000"
```

to

```
medium=popCol+">"+"500"+ " AND " +popCol+"<="+"10000"
```